# R: Standard Method for MCMC (Monte Carlo Markov Chain) Sampling

Tags: r, algorithm, function, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I have been trying to work on the following problem: **Given a multivariate joint probability distribution function, I am interested in learning how to randomly sample (using MCMC) a conditional probability distribution function.**

At the moment, I have found no "pre-made" way to do this, and have had to write the R code myself. The R code that I have written seems to work - but I am not sure if the R code is correct. I would be interested in finding a "pre-made" (e.g. some R package/library) which can do this. Below, I show the steps I have taken so far to solve this problem:

**Part 1 - Context:** Suppose I have a 4 Dimensional multivariate Normal Distribution:

[image]

Suppose this multivariate Normal Distribution P(X, Y, Z, W) distribution has a:

- Mean vector (4 x 1):

`5.0060022 3.4280049 1.4620007 0.2459998`

- Variance-Covariance Matrix (4 x 4):

````
[2,] 0.13080115 0.17604529 0.01603245 0.01221458 
[3,] 0.02084463 0.01603245 0.02808260 0.00601568 
[4,] 0.01309107 0.01221458 0.00601568 0.01042365 ```
````

**Part 2 - Function Definition**

Using the R programming language, I created a function that corresponds to this 4 Dimensional Multivariate Normal Distribution:

```
#define constants needed for the multivariate normal
    sigma1 <- c(0.15065114 , 0.13080115 ,  0.02084463 , 0.01309107 , 0.13080115 , 0.17604529 ,  0.01603245 , 0.01221458 , 0.02084463 , 0.01603245  , 0.02808260 , 0.00601568 , 0.01309107 , 0.01221458 ,  0.00601568 , 0.01042365)
      sigma <- matrix(sigma1, nrow=4, ncol= 4, byrow = TRUE)
      sigma_inv <- solve(sigma)
      sigma_det <- det(sigma)
      denom = sqrt( (2*pi)^4 * sigma_det) 

#actual multivariate function is defined below ("target")
    target <- function(x,y,z,w)
      
    {
      x_one = x - 5.0060022
      x_two = y - 3.4280049
      x_three = z - 1.4620007
      x_four = w - 0.2459998
        
      x_t = c(x_one, x_two, x_three, x_four)
      x_t_one <- matrix(x_t, nrow=4, ncol= 1, byrow = TRUE)
      x_t_two =  matrix(x_t, nrow=1, ncol= 4, byrow = TRUE)
      
      
      # In this part, as it's (x-mu)^T * SIGMA * (x-mu)
      
      #num = exp(-0.5 * t(x_t_t) %*% sigma1_inv %*% x_t_t)
      num = exp(-0.5 * x_t_two  %*%  sigma_inv  %*%  x_t_one)
        
      answer_1 = num/denom
      return(answer_1)
    }
```

**Part 3 - MCMC Code:**

Suppose I want to take random samples from this multivariate normal distribution **P(X, Y, Z, W), conditional on P(X, Y | Z = 2 , W = 1.3)**

I attempted to manually write a Monte Carlo Sampler (Metropolis-Hastings) to take random samples from **P(X, Y | Z = 2 , W = 1.3)**. To do this, I first "fixed" the values of Z and W within the original multivariate normal distribution:

```
#fix the definitions of w and z as per P(X, Y | Z = 2 , W = 1.3) 
target <- function(x,y)
          
        {
          x_one = x - 5.0060022
          x_two = y - 3.4280049
          x_three = 2 - 1.4620007
          x_four = 1.3 - 0.2459998
            
          x_t = c(x_one, x_two, x_three, x_four)
          x_t_one <- matrix(x_t, nrow=4, ncol= 1, byrow = TRUE)
          x_t_two =  matrix(x_t, nrow=1, ncol= 4, byrow = TRUE)
          
          
          # In this part, as it's (x-mu)^T * SIGMA * (x-mu)
          
          #num = exp(-0.5 * t(x_t_t) %*% sigma1_inv %*% x_t_t)
          num = exp(-0.5 * x_t_two  %*%  sigma_inv  %*%  x_t_one)
            
          answer_1 = num/denom
          return(answer_1)
        }
```

Next, I run the Monte Carlo Sampler (Metropolis-Hastings) to randomly sample this Conditional Distribution:

```
library(mvtnorm)
x = rep(0,10000)
y = rep(0,10000)

x[1] = 3     #initialize; I've set arbitrarily set this to 3 and 1
y[1] =1
for(i in 2:10000){
  current_x = x[i-1]
  current_y = y[i-1]
 
  new = rmvnorm(n=1, mean=c(current_x,current_y), sigma=diag(2), method="chol")   # generate bivariate random numbers
  proposed_x = new[1]
  proposed_y = new[2]

  A = target(proposed_x,proposed_y)/target(current_x,current_y) 
  if(runif(1)<A){
    x[i] = proposed_x       # accept move with probabily min(1,A)
    y[i] = proposed_y       
   
    } else {
    x[i] = current_x        # otherwise "reject" move, and stay where we are
    y[i] = current_y
 
    }
}
```

The results of the MCMC can be seen by calling `[x]` and `[y]`. **Thus, the final estimates would be:**

```
mean(mcmc_output$x)
[1] 6.281715

mean(mcmc_output$y)
[1] 4.63817
```

**(Optional) Part 4 - Visualize Results:**

Now, I can plot the histograms for the results:

```
mcmc_output = data.frame(x,y)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(density(mcmc_output$y, main = "Density of Y"))
plot(density(mcmc_output$x, main = "Density of X"))
```

[image]

I can also look at the contour plots of these MCMC samples:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mcmc_output, aes(x = x, y = 
          y)) +
        geom_density_2d_filled() + 
        ggtitle("Contour Plots of the MCMC Estimates")
```

[image]

**Question:** Is there a "easier" (standard) way to do this (MCMC Sampling of Custom Defined Functions) in R using a well known and pre-built package/library? The code I have written seems long and inefficient - and probably contains some mistakes as well. Does anyone know about, or can anyone recommend a package/library in R that does this?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm
- https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/MH-examples1.html